# Data sheet clarification for JTD1524S12

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, emc

I am trying to design a PCB for [JTD1524S12](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_JTD15.pdf) DC-DC converter. I was going through the datasheet and on  page 3 the following tables are provided:

[image]

I got the idea that these tables are related to EMC.

On the first table "EMC:Emissions" in "Notes and conditions" it is said that "No external components required".

Does it mean that, if no external components are used there are "Emissions"?

And according to second table, if suggested components are used there will be "immunity" from the emissions?

If someone could help me understand what these table are trying to convey, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpet that to mean no components are needed to meet the listed emissions requirements. What the second table is saying is that you would require those components to be able to survive or continue to operate without interference during the high voltage transients that can occur during events like switching or indirect lightning strikes.